# Java Returning a Boolean Error

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return, collision

I am a new-comer to the java language, and I'm confused as to why I am getting an error here.
It's a very short piece of code that I seem to have a mental block about.
Any suggestions?

```
public class Rigidbody {
    public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float y2,float size2){
        if(Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)^2)+((y2-y1)^2))<=(size1+size2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?  (It's probably really obvious).

Comment: Just for future reference, it's always more helpful if you post the actual error rather than just saying "I am a getting an error." It looks like several people already figured out the problem, but they probably could have done it even faster with the help of the error message.

Comment: Your code doesnt returns boolean if `if` condition is not satisfied so, in else part you need to return else. For these type of coding its better to use  `flags`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, firstly, [you forgot to have an `else` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083785/591495):

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1,
    float x2, float y2, float r2) {
  if (Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2)) <= (r1 + r2)){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[Someone else already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083789/591495) this can be shortened as follows:

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1,
    float x2, float y2, float r2) {
  return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) ^ 2) + ((y2 - y1) ^ 2)) <= (r1 + r2);
}
```

(make sure to upvote them for pointing those out :-)

---

However, your code is still wrong.

As stated [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), Java's `^` operator is for *exclusive bitwise OR*, not exponentiation. Perhaps you want [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double))?

> Returns the value of the first argument raised to the power of the second argument.

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1,
    float x2, float y2, float r2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)) <= (r1 + r2);
}
```

Or, you can also just use [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot(double,%20double)) rather than rolling your own!

> Returns sqrt(x^2 + y^2) without intermediate overflow or underflow.

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1, float y1, float r1,
    float x2, float y2, float r2) {
  return Math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1) <= (r1 + r2);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. `Math.pow()` is what the OP wants :)

Comment: Thank you, for pointing out my errors.
Also thanks for the shortcut tip!

Answer (score 11):

You can make the method's body much simpler...

```
public class Rigidbody {
    public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float y2,float size2){
        return Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)^2)+((y2-y1)^2))<=(size1+size2)    
    }
}
```

The result of `<=` is always a Boolean.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot the `else` part of the `if`.

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float y2,float size2){
    if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2)+ Math.pow(y2-y1,2)) <= (size1+size2)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float y2,float size2){
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2)+ Math.pow(y2-y1,2)) <= (size1+size2);
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, as noted by **@veer**, you are using `^2` when you should be using `Math.pow`, since the `^` operator in Java is a bitwise XOR, not the power operator. So go **upvote and accept his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083804/140816)**, as that is the main cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I have used Math.pow for the square. Also added return statement for the else condition.

```
        public class Rigidbody {

     public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float                     y2,float size2){
            return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2-y1), 2)) <= (size1+size2));   
     } }
```

Comment: (P.S.Do not forget to vote up the answer and mark it as resolved. I need it)

Answer (score 2):

OP has a problem in his/her code due to the `^` symbol usage that should be replaced by `Math#pow()`, good point every one! But he/she's asking **what its missing**. The answer is very simple: every method must return a value, *except* for `void` methods.

If you have

```
public boolean aBooleanMethod(int x) {
    //some fancy and nice code!
    return true;
}
```

The compiler will be happy. But, if you do something like this:

```
public boolean anotherBooleanMethod(int x) {
    if (x < 2) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The compiler will throw an exception:

> This method must return a result of type boolean.

Why is this? Because at the end of the method, the compiler find a path that could not return a value, so instead of make your program crash or return an unexpected result (like `false` when there is no return associated), the Java compiler will throw the exception.

How to solve it? Easy: **don't forget to return a value** on every path in your method.

Ways to solve the problem in the last piece of code:

1. Adding a default `return` at the end of the method. This is a common approach used by almost all programmers.

   ```
   public boolean anotherBooleanMethod(int x) {
       if (x < 2) {
           return true;
       }
       //if the method has never returned true, then it must return false...
       return false;
   }
   ```
2. For boolean results, you can return a condition:

   ```
   public boolean anotherBooleanMethod(int x) {
       //your method always return a value, no compiler problems
       //the value depends if x is less than 2 (true) or 2 or more (false)
       return (x < 2);
   }
   ```

About the exception of the `void` methods, this doesn't mean that a void method can't use the `return` keyword, just means that it must return "nothing". To post a sample:

```
public void theVoidMethod(int x) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to theVoidMethod!");
    if (x < 2) {
        //return nothing! End of the method
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("You've reached the bottom of theVoidMethod!");
    //here, the Java compiler will add a return sentence for you, no need to code it
    //return
}
```

If you test this method using 1 and 2 as parameters you will get different results:

theVoidMethod(1):

```
Welcome to theVoidMethod!
```

theVoidMethod(2):

```
Welcome to theVoidMethod!
You've reached the bottom of theVoidMethod!
```

Now, to solve another problems in your code, you should use the `Math#pow` method instead of `^` symbol, but that's heavily explained in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

when that condition false it not return any thing that's why it wrong.

```
public class Rigidbody {
public boolean checkCircleCollision(float x1,float y1,float size1,float x2,float y2,float size2){
    if(Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)^2)+((y2-y1)^2))<=(size1+size2)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
}
```